# More precedence/specificity to CSS class in LESS

Tags: css, less, css-specificity

I've a LESS code like:

```
.block__element {
  background: red;
  &--modifier {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

I want more specificity to .block__element--modifier such as:

```
.block__element.block__element--modifier {
  background: yellow:
}
```

So that it can overrides some other styles.
I can achieve it by:

```
.block__element {
  background: red;
  &--modifier.block__element {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

I want to know is there any easy way?

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: [Like this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.block__element%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20background%3A%20red%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%26--modifier%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background%3A%20yellow%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D) probably, though honestly I don't really understand the problem (is it just about typed characters economy? But why two classes? Should not just `.block__element--modifier {background: yellow}` be enough? Sounds like spoiling the very purpose of BEM).

Comment: @Laurens current approach works. And I am currently using it. I was just wondering.

Comment: @seven-phases-max That's great approach. So '&' symbol will just replace the parent i think, regardless of the position! I was just wondering how can I achieve this.

Comment: Yep. There's even a dedicated [issue](https://github.com/less/less-docs/issues/40) in the docs repo. And the corresponding [section](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-multiple-) in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.block__element {
    background: red;
    &&--modifier {
        background: yellow;
    }
}
```

[link](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.block__element%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20background%3A%20red%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%26--modifier%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background%3A%20yellow%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D)

Comment: the problem is when we have multiple parent elements. then && makes them repeat too and messes up the whole styling.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it in a more fancy way using **variable interpolation**, so that every time you need to increase the specificity of a class/modifier you can use it.
It seems weird at first, but when you'll get used to it you will love it and your code will look much more clean and easy to read.

[Check the official documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation)

```
.block__element {
    @this: block__element;
    background: red;

    &.@{this}--modifier-primary {
        background: yellow;
    }

    &.@{this}--modifier-secondary {
        background: green;
    }

    &.@{this}--modifier-tertiary {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think solution of  seven-phases-max is more clean